# How to fetch sql query results in airflow using JDBC operator

Tags: jdbc, airflow

I have configured JDBC connection in Airflow connections. My Task part of DAG looks like below which contains a select statement. When triggering the DAG is success, but my the query results are not printed in log. How to fetch the results of the query using JDBC operator.

dag = DAG(dag_id='test_azure_sqldw_v1',
default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=None,dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=120),)

sql="select count(*) from tablename"

azure_sqldw=JdbcOpetask_id='azure_sqldw',sql=sql,jdbc_conn_id="cdf_sqldw",autocommit=True,dag=dag)

Comment: why do you expect the result to be printed into the logs?

Answer (score 1):

The operator does not print to the log. It just run the query.
If you want to fetch results to do something with it you need to use the hook.

```
from airflow.providers.jdbc.hooks.jdbc import JdbcHook

def func(jdbc_conn_id, sql, **kwargs):
    """Print df from JDBC """
    pprint(kwargs)
    hook = JdbcHook(jdbc_conn_id=jdbc_conn_id)
    df = hook.get_pandas_df(sql=sql,autocommit=True)
    print(df.to_string())


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task',
    python_callable=func,
    op_kwargs={'jdbc_conn_id': 'cdf_sqldw', 'sql': 'select count(*) from tablename' }, 
    dag=dag,
)
```

You can also create a custom operator that does the required action you seek.