# Redirecting MySqlOperator console output to airflow log

Tags: airflow

I have a task in an Airflow job that uses the MySqlOperator. It looks like this:

```
  show_tables_master = MySqlOperator(
        task_id="show_tables_master",
        mysql_conn_id="dbjobs_master_mysql",
        sql=r"""SHOW OPEN TABLES;""",
        dag=dag,
        database="mydb",
        autocommit=True,
    )
```

The whole purpose of this task is to get the output of SHOW OPEN TABLES, but I don't see the open tables coming out in the Airflow log. All I see is that the query had 2 rows of results.

How can I redirect the output of my "SHOW OPEN TABLES" query to the Airflow log?

Answer (score 0):

Based off of [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65578237/how-to-fetch-sql-query-results-in-airflow-using-jdbc-operator?rq=1), I solved this using the PythonOperator like so:

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.mysql.hooks.mysql import MySqlHook

#custom function
def func(mysql_conn_id, sql, database, **kwargs):
    """Print results of sql query """
    hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id=mysql_conn_id, schema=database)
    df = hook.get_pandas_df(sql=sql)
    print(df.to_string())

#airflow task
show_tables_master = PythonOperator(
        task_id="show_tables_master",
        python_callable=func,
        op_kwargs={"mysql_conn_id": "dbjobs_master_mysql", "sql": """SHOW OPEN TABLES;""", "database": "mydb"}, 
        dag=dag,
    )
```